# pyads: Read PLC value depending on other value change

Tags: python, python-3.x, twincat-ads

I would like to get the current value of a REAL variable in dependence of an other BOOL variable using a OnChange notification:

```
@plc.notification(pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL)
def callback(handle, name, timestamp, value):
    if value==True:
        print(f"handle: {handle}")
        print(f"name: {name}")
        print(f"timestamp: {timestamp}")
        print(f"value: {value}")
        print(plc.read_by_name(f"GVL_MyValues.MyRealValue", plc_datatype=pyads.PLCTYPE_REAL))
```

Then I add this callback to my changing bool variable:

```
plc.add_device_notification(f'MAIN.MyBoolValue', 
                                        pyads.NotificationAttrib(sizeof(pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL)),
                                        callback)
```

Everything except the RealValue is printed when MyBoolValue changes to True.
Do I have to configure something else or does pyads not support `read_by_name()` (I also tried `symbol.read()`) within a notification callback?

Comment: But something must be printed. What is the output of the last `print` line?

Comment: When I execute the last print as standalone (as seperate Jupyter cell) the current REAL value is printed properly. But within the callback it is just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected a `read_by_name()` within the callback using the same TC client as the callback is not possible. I use a second plc object to execute the read within the callback as workaround. For more information see https://github.com/stlehmann/pyads/issues/259